# how to unit test the following code

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm currently stuck on trying to create a unit test for the following code;

```
using System;

namespace EuroMonitorTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int answer = 5;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number less then 5");
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (value <= answer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number required to get to  5 is " + (answer - value));
            }
            else if (value > answer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That number is over 5, Try Again");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What tests are you trying to write?

Comment: im trying to right and mstest

Comment: To test what behaviour specifically?

Comment: really to test what happens if the value is over 5, and for me to get rid of the if else statements.

Answer (score 1):

you might consider to extract the logic to a seperate class. For exemple, you could create a class that receive a "value input" and an "answer input" + a method that return a string. It will help you separate the reponsabilities of your program.

look at this link : http://haroldrv.com/2015/02/using-test-driven-development-tdd-to-solve-fizzbuzz/

Comment: Would doing it like that make it operate in the same way?

Comment: the problem with your code is that you are trying to test 2 things at once. First, you the the logic to know what you gonna display and second you have the "real" display in the console

Comment: if i get rid of the else statement would that solve the problem?

Comment: @lpjk no - you need to separate out the concepts of calculation and display in this code to make it testable

Comment: exactly Single Responsability principle